# Is there something like "Hydration" in Nativescript?

Tags: angular, vue.js, nativescript

Phonegap has this theoretically awesome feature: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/tools/hydration/
In combination with CD this could provide very fast and effective deployments.

Do you think there is any possiblity of implementing this in a Nativescript app?

I'm not very familiar with any iOS or Android specifics, but shouldn't it be possible to replace the Javascript part of the app with some kind of OTA-update?

I'd appreciate every thoughts about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like Microsoft Codepush, pushing live updates to device without hitting app store / google play. We have a [open feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/issues/247) with Codepush for years now.

With upcoming NativeScript release (v6.0), we have [App Sync](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-app-sync) (beta as of today). That should do that job for you.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for!